# pip appears to be installing to the wrong location

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, paramiko

I am trying to install paramiko library to python 2.7, but it is getting installed to a directory that python is not searching. The sys.path in python is:

`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Yet when I installed `paramiko`, it went here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`

I suspect it has something to do with the version of pip (pip2) that I used to install `paramiko`, but I can't seem to fix this for the life of me.

Comment: Are you on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

try this command

```
pip install paramiko --user
```

to install by user.

Answer (score 1):

You can add paths to sys.path so that libraries will be imported from wherever you want.

`import sys`
`sys.path.append("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python"`

That should fix your problem